# How to select specific columns and remove then add a character string to the end of them in r

Tags: r, string, dplyr, multiple-columns, rename

I have a very large dataset with three waves of data. I want to standardized the column names so that the wave designation is at the end of every variable. I successfully did it but am looking for a more succinct way to do it. My data looks like this:

```
toy <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(sample(1:100, 5)),
                           c(sample(1:100, 5)),
                           c(sample(1:100, 5)),
                           c(sample(1:100, 5)),
                           c(sample(1:100, 5)),
                           c(sample(1:100, 5))))
colnames(toy) <- c(paste0(LETTERS[1:4], "w", c(1,1,2,2)))
colnames(toy)[c(5,6)] <- c(paste0("w3", LETTERS[5:6]))
```

so that the output is:

```
toy
  Aw1 Bw1 Cw2 Dw2 w3E w3F
1  49  23  66  20  34  76
2  50  75  69  21  47  41
3  88  61  19  77  45   7
4  79  94  48  19  61  23
5  83  17  79  35  14  21
```

I want it to be like this where the third wave is formatted like the other two:

```
  Aw1 Bw1 Cw2 Dw2 Ew3 Fw3
1  49  23  66  20  34  76
2  50  75  69  21  47  41
3  88  61  19  77  45   7
4  79  94  48  19  61  23
5  83  17  79  35  14  21
```

This is what I've done that works:

```
t1.toy <- toy %>% rename_at(vars(contains("w3")),
                  .funs = list(function(x) paste0(x, "temp")))
t2.toy <- t1.toy %>% rename_at(vars(contains("w3")),
                            .funs = list(function(x) gsub(x = x, 
                                                          pattern = "w3", 
                                                          replacement = "")))
t3.toy <- t2.toy %>% rename_at(vars(contains("temp")),
                               .funs = list(function(x) gsub(x = x, 
                                                             pattern = "temp", 
                                                             replacement = "w3")))
```

Any other quicker ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the following code

```
toy <- `names<-`(toy,gsub("(.*?\\d+)(.*)","\\2\\1",names(toy)))
```

Comment: @garsimpitoyable `(.*?\\d+)` matches the cases where a letter is followed by digits, and `(.*)` refers to the the chars afters that. Here, `(.*?\\d+)` and `(.*)`  correspond to `\\1` and `\\2`. In `gsub()`, `\\2\\1` means we swap the found patterns from the original `\\1\\2`

Answer (score 1):

May be we need to capture as a group

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
toy %>% 
   rename_at(vars(contains('w3')), ~ str_replace(., '(.*\\d+)(.*)', "\\2\\1"))
#  Aw1 Bw1 Cw2 Dw2 Ew3 Fw3
#1  49  23  66  20  34  76
#2  50  75  69  21  47  41
#3  88  61  19  77  45   7
#4  79  94  48  19  61  23
#5  83  17  79  35  14  21
```

---

Or if this needs to be done automatically, we can use `rename_all`

```
toy %>%
    rename_all(~ str_replace(., "^([a-z]\\w+)([A-Z])$", "\\2\\1"))
```

#### data

```
toy <- structure(list(Aw1 = c(49L, 50L, 88L, 79L, 83L), Bw1 = c(23L, 
75L, 61L, 94L, 17L), Cw2 = c(66L, 69L, 19L, 48L, 79L), Dw2 = c(20L, 
21L, 77L, 19L, 35L), w3E = c(34L, 47L, 45L, 61L, 14L), w3F = c(76L, 
41L, 7L, 23L, 21L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `colnames`:

```
colnames(toy) <- gsub("^(w3)(.+)$", "\\2\\1", colnames(toy))
```

which outputs for `toy`

```
  Aw1 Bw1 Cw2 Dw2 Ew3 Fw3
1  49  23  66  20  34  76
2  50  75  69  21  47  41
3  88  61  19  77  45   7
4  79  94  48  19  61  23
5  83  17  79  35  14  21
```